# Pushing element into array stored in a jld2 file in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I am trying to push an element into an array that is already stored in a .jld2 file, however after closing the file and reading it again, the array is not updated.

```
using JLD2

jldopen("example.jld2", "w") do file
    file["mygroup/mystuff"] = [1,2]
end

jldopen("example.jld2", "a+") do file
    push!(file["mygroup"]["mystuff"], 3)
    println(file["mygroup"]["mystuff"])
    # The array should be updated to [1,2,3], and it is also working up to here
end

jldopen("example.jld2", "r") do file
    println(file["mygroup"]["mystuff"][3])
    # I got BoundsError here, for when I am reading the array again, it becomes [1,2] again
    # as if it were never updated.
end
```

So how should I push an element into an array stored in a .jld2 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is the same underlying issue as with python's Shelve; e.g. see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shelve.html#example (the bits in the code talking about writeback).

Effectively you cannot append / push!, <s>and you should rely on replacing the contents of that entry altogether if you want the change to persist</s>. UPDATE: apologies, the api is not clear, but it seems you cannot overwrite groups in this manner. (there is no `delete!` method or similar that applies to `JLD2.Group`s ).

Therefore while you can 'append' new groups and variables to a JLD2 file, presumably you cannot 'update' one in the manner you are trying to do, and you're better off reading a file in and recreating the updated file from scratch.